# class inheritance in ruby on rails - monkeypatching/overriding belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance

Simple Rails question. I have a model Foo which looks like this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :bar

  def self.belongs_to(association_id, options = {})
    puts "HI"
    super
  end
end
```

How come when I load Foo in irb

```
>> Foo
=> Foo(id: integer, bar_id: integer)
>>
```

I don't see "HI" (I'm fairly certain Rails calls belongs_to when the class is loaded)? Yet, when I type Foo.belongs_to("anything_here") I see:

```
>> Foo.belongs_to("anything_here")
HI
=> nil
>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish (looks a bit nasty!).

Either way, though, the order of the definition and the call matter:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.belongs_to(association_id, options = {})
    puts "HI"
    super
  end

  belongs_to :bar
end
```

Comment: Just trying to understand the interplay of inheritance and method overriding. Thanks. This answers my question.